# Semantic UI - Inline Dropdown Appearing Beneath Other Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

Essentially, the issue is that the drop down that's created with `.ui.inline.dropdown` is appearing beneath the rest of the fields in the code below it. Both of which are in an accordion.

My first instinct was to just give the drop down a high `z-index` and the inputs a lower z-index, but this doesn't appear to have any effect on the issue.

This is the html:

```
<div class="ui accordion">
    <div class="title">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        Advanced
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h4>
          Results match 
          <div class="ui inline dropdown">
              <div class="text">any</div>
              <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
              <div class="menu">
                  <div class="active item" data-text="any">Any</div>
                  <div class="item" data-text="all">All</div>
                  <div class="item" data-text="none">None</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          of the fields below.
        </h4>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="firstName">Name</label>
            <div class="two fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" autocomplete="off" placeholder="First Name">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Last Name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and this is how I'm initializing the drop down and accordion:

```
$( '.ui.accordion' ).accordion();
$( '.ui.dropdown' ).dropdown();
```